# Cocoon gem, deep association not built when edit or error raised

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, cocoon-gem

I'm using the [Cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) to build a nested form with a field_for containing another field_for. The hierarchy looks like this:
-Letter form
 -Card field_for
  -Button field_for

I have a `link_to_add_association`in order to dynamically add cards with their buttons. This part looks like this:

```
<div class="connected-carousels">
                  <div class="stage">
                      <div class="carousel carousel-stage">
                          <ul id="carousel-stage-ul">
                            <%= f.fields_for :cards do |card_fields| %>
                              <% if @blabla %>
                                <%= render 'card_fields', f: card_fields %>
                              <% end %>
                            <% end %>
                            <% end %>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="prev prev-stage"><span>&lsaquo;</span></a>
                        <a href="#" class="next next-stage"><span>&rsaquo;</span></a>
                    </div>
              <div class="navigation">
                  <a href="#" class="prev prev-navigation">&lsaquo;</a>
                  <a href="#" class="next next-navigation">&rsaquo;</a>
                  <div class="carousel carousel-navigation">
                    <ul id="carousel-navigation-ul"></ul>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <%= link_to_add_association '+ Add Card', f, :cards, id: 'add-card-button-bis', data: { association_insertion_node: '#carousel-stage-ul', association_insertion_method: :append } %>
              </div>
            </div>
```

_card_fields.html.erb partial rendering the buttons:

```
<% f.object.buttons.build %>
  <%= f.fields_for :buttons do |button_card_fields| %>
      <%= render 'button_fields', f: button_card_fields %>
  <% end %>
```

_button_fields.html.erb partial:

```
<div class="add-button-card-modal">
  <h4>Add New Button</h4>
  <label>Button Text</label>
  <%= f.text_field :button_text, :maxlength => 20, placeholder: "Enter the text to display on the button..." %>
  <br><br>
  <label>Button URL</label>
  <%= f.text_field :button_url, placeholder: "Paste URL..." %>
  <div class="nav-popups-buttons">
    <button type="button" id="validate_new_card_button" class="small-cta2">Add Button</button>
    <p class="remove-link" id="delete_new_card_button">Remove Button</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Letter model:

```
class Letter < ApplicationRecord
  validates :campaign_name, :presence => true

  belongs_to :core_bot
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :cards, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :filters, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :analytic_deliveries, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :analytic_reads, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :analytic_sends, dependent: :destroy


  accepts_nested_attributes_for :filters, allow_destroy: true, :reject_if => :all_blank
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :messages, allow_destroy: true, :reject_if => :all_blank
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cards, allow_destroy: true, :reject_if => :all_blank
end
```

Card model:

```
class Card < ApplicationRecord
  validates :remote_image_url, :format => URI::regexp(%w(http https)), presence: { message: '%{value} : please enter valid url' }, :allow_blank => true
  validates :title, :subtitle, :presence => true

  belongs_to :letter, optional: true
  has_many :buttons, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :buttons, :reject_if => Proc.new { |att| att[:button_text].blank? && att[:button_url].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Button model:

```
class Button < ApplicationRecord
  validates :button_url, :format => URI::regexp(%w(http https)), presence: { message: '%{value} : please enter valid url' },
    unless: Proc.new { |a| a.button_url.blank? }
  validates :button_text, :presence => true, unless: Proc.new { |a| a.button_url.blank? }

  belongs_to :message, optional: true
  belongs_to :card, optional: true
  has_one :short_url, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Create action in the letter controller in case of error raised:

```
@letter.filters.build

        if params[:letter]['cards_attributes'].present? == false
          @letter.cards.build.buttons.build
        end

        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @letter.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
```

The problem is that buttons are not built when the create action raises an error or when I edit the record. If I add `@letter.cards.build.buttons.build` into the controller, it adds a new card but buttons inputs still don't appear.

UPDATE
In fact buttons are built. The only problem is my custom jquery I am using to display the popup showing the buttons fields are not working since there were created in the cocoon:after-insert callback.

When an error is raised or on the edit view, the cards I created are rendered instead of added by link_to_add_association. This the cocoon:after-insert callback is not called...

Any idea how I could use the same logic of link_to_add_association calling the after-insert callback on rendered cards fields?

Here is the console test, my buttons are here:
[image: Console Test]

Comment: Is `Button_fields `, `card_field_partial` the actual file name or do you have proper rails names & just forgot to include them?

Comment: Also, have you removed the IF statement surrounding the initial `<%= render 'card_fields', f: card_fields %>`?  Do you have tests setup to ensure the if statement fires correctly during a failure raised by the form?

Comment: I edited the question with file names. Actually I thought I needed the render but it seems I don't since I dynamically add all fields in it...

Comment: This might be redundant ... but you should need only one `.build`...it builds the whole relationship working backwards ... `@letter.cards.build.buttons.build`, try it as `@letter.cards.buttons.build`

Comment: Then I get: 'undefined method `buttons' for #<Card::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fae4f40b208>'

Comment: Edit from my previous comment, I need the render*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157988/discussion-between-mirv-and-alphanico).

Comment: And what does the `after_insert` do? You can normally easily do the same after loading the page?

Comment: Yep that's what I did, problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so normally there's a couple issues buried in one of these problems.  This answer is only to trouble shoot why the `Edit` view always fails to load.

My initial guess is in the controller, two problems ... the `if params` & the `@letter.cards.build.buttons.build` is the problem & instead of trying to design around it - you need to change it, accept whatever the error is & then fix that error in the models.  The first fix is get the conditional `if params` out of there.

I also noticed there's no `accept_nested_attributes_for :buttons` on your letter model.

Lastly, before we begin trouble shooting - I forgot to ask for your strong_params section - please post the entire controller action for `create` & the strong_params method in the private section of the controller.

---

Since it's not loading at all.  Ever.  It's probably not a totally a jquery issue.  We should see a rails generated collection of all the cards & buttons belonging via the model.

I'm guessing so the `.build` method is the first issue ...

I imagine if you examine the rails console ... `rails c` ...

First, try calling `@test = Letter.first`, then explore it's values when it sets ... you should be able to see other ID's in there & then be able to call them with `@test.{whatever}` .. ie: `@test.cards` which will give a collection of all the cards that exist via the relationship in the models.

Second, if the first fails, `@test.cards.create!(name: "test")` to see if the relationship creates the entry correctly.  I'd be happy if anything shows up in `@letter.cards.buttons` in console, then we trouble shoot the other branches (`letter.filters`) of your hierarchy later.

Third, we move generating test data via console to ensure those values exist to be fed thru the rails controller & to the view to be displayed.

Fourth, we check the jquery isn't interfering with them being displayed.

---

**Demo code**

Here's the 3 deep nesting ...

*Note all of this worked & took no effort for the `EDIT`, the setup for new/create in the `_form.html.erb` just automatically worked for editing.*

Models

```
country.rb

class Country < ApplicationRecord
  has_many  :states
  has_many  :counties, through: :states

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :states, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes[:name].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :counties, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes[:name].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
end

state.rb
class State < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to  :country
  has_many    :counties

  validates :name, presence: true

  # can't recall if this is needed 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :counties, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes[:name].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
end

county.rb
class County < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :state
  validates :name
end
```

countries_controller.rb  ... Controller (you don't even need to generate a controller for others)

```
class CountriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_country, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @countries = Country.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @country = Country.new
  end

  def edit
    # @partial_choice = params[:partial_choice]
  end

  def create
    @country = Country.new(country_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @country.save
        format.html { redirect_to @country, notice: 'Country was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @country }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @country.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @country.update!(country_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @country, notice: 'Country was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @country }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @country.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @country.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to countries_url, notice: 'Country was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_country
    @country = Country.find(params[:id])
  end


 def country_params
  params.require(:country).permit(:id, :name, :description, :size, :player_id,
     countryneighbor_attritubtes: [:id, :bordercountry_id, :country_id, :_destroy],
     states_attributes: [:id, :name, :description, :country_id, :_destroy,
     counties_attributes: [:id, :name, :description, :state_id, :_destroy]])
  end
end
```

Views - if you've already tested the data & relationships, `strong_params` in rails console as well as checked server logs in `log/development.log`, then maybe compare the HAML style calls in the views here ...

`/basicB/app/views/countries/_form.html.haml`

```
.fieldset.form-inline
  = simple_form_for @country do |f|
    = f.error_notification
    .countries
      = f.input :name, input_html: {:placeholder => "...insert country name..."}
      = f.input :description
    .row-fuild
      %a.btn.btn-primary{"aria-controls" => "neighborsDisplay", "aria-expanded" => "false", "data-toggle" => "collapse", :href => "#neighborsDisplay"} Show Neighbors
      #neighborsDisplay.collapse
        .list-group
          - for neighbor in @country.neighbors
            = render partial: 'country_neighbors', locals: {neighbor: neighbor}
      .states
      = f.simple_fields_for :states do |state|
        = render 'state_fields', :f => state
    .links.row
      = link_to_add_association 'Add State', f, :states,  render_options: { wrapper: 'inline_form' }, :class => "btn btn-default"
    .form-actions.row
      = f.button :submit
```

`/app/views/countries/_state_fields.html.haml`

```
.nested-fields.list-group-item
    .well
        %h4 State
        .form-inline.text
            = f.input :name, input_html: {:placeholder => "...insert State Name ..."} 
            = f.input :description
            = link_to_remove_association f, class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs' do
                .glyphicon.glyphicon-remove
        .counties
        = f.simple_fields_for :counties do |state|
            = render 'county_fields', :f => state
    .links.row
        = link_to_add_association 'Add County', f, :counties,  render_options: { wrapper: 'inline_form' }, :class => "btn btn-default"
```

`/app/views/countries/_county_fields.html.haml`

```
.nested-fields.list-group-item.my-well
  .row.text
    = f.input :name, input_html: {:placeholder => "... County Name ..."}
    = f.input :description
    = link_to_remove_association f, class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs' do
      .glyphicon.glyphicon-remove
```

Comment: I edited my question with the console test, everything works well, just the custom jquery I use after-insert. Please, let's keep going on the new question related to the jquery part ;)

Comment: Can we pop a new question to show it's a different question & then link from both?  It makes it easier for people to follow or filter out the useful parts when they follow from internet.